# Android phone is listening to Bluetooth connection but the Bluetooth device fails to connect

Tags: bluetooth, spp

The device is Omron Bluetooth Blood Pressure Monitor 708-BT here.

The health device is already paired to my HTC Sensation running Android 4.0.3.

The health device initiates the connection and my Android app is supposed to accept it. The app is set to target API level 16 with min API level 11.

Everything was working fine yesterday and then it suddenly stop working.

My thread to accept incoming connections from the health device is standard taken from Google's BluetoothChat sample. Code is included below. No exception is throw and log cat is showing that my phone is listening to incoming connections just fine.

Where do I start to test this kind of issue?

AcceptThread:

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private String mSocketType;

        public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {

                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_HEALTH_MON, MY_UUID);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                    "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothSPPService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                    mSocketType);
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

LogCat:

```
08-02 17:44:41.055: D/BluetoothSPPService(2956): start
08-02 17:44:41.055: D/BluetoothSPPService(2956): setState() 0 -> 1
08-02 17:45:49.491: D/BluetoothSPPService(2956): Socket Type: SecureBEGIN mAcceptThreadThread[Thread-6798,5,main]
08-02 17:46:07.159: D/BluetoothSPPService(2956): Socket Type: InsecureBEGIN mAcceptThreadThread[Thread-6799,5,main]
08-02 17:48:29.938: D/BluetoothSPPService(3388): start
08-02 17:48:29.938: D/BluetoothSPPService(3388): setState() 0 -> 1
08-02 17:48:41.049: D/BluetoothSPPService(3388): Socket Type: SecureBEGIN mAcceptThreadThread[Thread-6837,5,main]
08-02 17:48:42.730: D/BluetoothSPPService(3388): Socket Type: InsecureBEGIN mAcceptThreadThread[Thread-6838,5,main]
```

Comment: The Android bluetooth stack is a little bit unstable. Try rebooting the phone and/or just turning bluetooth on/off.
Does the bluetooth icon blinking in Android ?

Comment: Thanks @Skaard-Solo, I've tried all that. What do you mean by bluetooth icon blinking, I've never seen such a thing before?

Comment: Well, when you open a listening socket, Android register a Channel and a BlutoothService name. Then, when some kind of SSP device want to connect to your thread, Android detect this channel and this BTservice name. That's why I ask the question. If BT icon blink, this is because the channel or BTservice name doesn't match ;)

Comment: What I meant is either my HTC Sensation, Samsung Galaxy S3, HTC Desire or the health device has Bluetooth icon. I suppose yours does. What is your device that you're referring to?